# How to properly type navigation passed as props with React-Navigation with expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

How do I properly type navigation passed as props to another component? As per the docs

Each screen component in your app is provided with the navigation prop automatically.

And also,

To type check our screens, we need to annotate the navigation prop and the route prop received by a screen.

```
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;
```

I have a navigation component with router:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [userMetrics, setUserMetrics] = useState<UserMetrics>(null);
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
  return (
    <UserMetricsContext.Provider value={{ userMetrics, setUserMetrics }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Tests" component={Tests} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </UserMetricsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And in Home screen  I want to receive navigation prop to pass it down further to form which have a button that will navigate to Tests component and pass form data as params:

```
interface Props {
  navigation: NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Home">;
}

export const Home: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { setUserMetrics } =
    useContext<IUserMetricsContextType>(UserMetricsContext);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <HealthCheckForm onSubmit={setUserMetrics} navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

and now the problem starts to be visible in form component because typescript is assuming one level too much, I have typed the props like I did in the parent Home component like so:

```
interface Props {
  onSubmit: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserMetrics>>;
  navigation: NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Home">;
}
```

and typescript wants me to use it like so:

```
  const submitHandler = (data: UserMetrics) => {
    onSubmit(data);
    navigation.navigation.navigate("Tests", { userMetrics: data });
    console.log(data);
  };
```

This is not working however, the correct - working and navigating usage is

```
navigation.navigate("Tests", { userMetrics: data });
```

and when I navigate to the Tests component and pass the params along, I don't know how to receive them in Test component. I am trying to do it analogically like so:

```
interface Props {
  navigation: NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Tests">;
}

export const Tests: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { userMetrics } =
    useContext<IUserMetricsContextType>(UserMetricsContext);
  console.log({ params: navigation.route.params });
  return (
    <View>
      <DisplayList />
    </View>
  );
};
```

And I get yet another error about reading properties of undefined.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are solutions for nested Navigators (starting point here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/). However, in this case I would suggest not making your `HealthCheckForm` have any awareness of the navigation state. Just pass it a standard `onSubmit()` prop and handle all the navigation within the `Home` component.

Also as a tip make sure to set up your `RootStackParamList` correctly so that the "tests" route is expecting `{userMetrics: YourDataType}`. Here is a random example of setting that up.

```js
export type RootStackParamList = {
    myRouteName: undefined;
    tests: { userMetrics: MyDataType }; // TS now expects MyDataType on the props for tests route
    terminalAndMate: {
        departingTerminal: WSFTerminal;
        arrivingTerminal: WSFTerminal;
    };
...
```

I would also suggest typing your screen props this way instead of as an interface. NativeStackScreenProps can carry params as defined on the rootStackParamList:

```
type TestsScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "tests">;
```

With those two changes, the `tests` screen should have `props.route.params`, which will contain MyDataType.

try: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/typescript/

**-addition in regards to Seven's comment-**

Take a look at the type declaration for NativeStackScreenProps.

```js
export declare type NativeStackScreenProps<ParamList extends ParamListBase, RouteName extends keyof ParamList = string> = {
    navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
    route: RouteProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
};
```

By making the interface as you did, you are saying the type of `props` for that component is

```
{ navigation: { navigation: NativeStackNavigation..etc , route: RouteProp }}
```

You can see that it is double nested and not necessary as the type provided by the library supports all of the functionality you need.

**onsubmit**
Your onSubmit function would look something like this:

```
//home.tsx
const onSubmit = (data: YourDataType) => {
props.navigation.navigate("tests", { userMetrics: data});
}

return (
//...stuff
<YourFormComponent onSubmit={onSubmit} />
```

This way all your navigation is handled by home, which is on the same 'level' as tests, and you keep your navigation a little cleaner.

Shouldn't need any useEffect calls.

Comment: Hi @Tyles S thanks a lot, would you explain why is type preferable over interface here? And in this situation on button click I would just update the state in App component which is then distributed via Context Api, so where would I be changing screens, in useEffect in App? Can this be considered an effect, and shouldn't that be managed in the click handler? Again thanks a lot for clarifications.

Comment: See my appended answer. The comment box was insufficient :)